# How do i create a list(array) of values with the number of times they appear in another array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to generate a list of "Products" that details the amount of times each "Product appears in a mysql query.

Outline:
1. Get the last 30 days of orders from the database. 

2. Get the products that appear in those orders. 

3. Get a count of the times a product appears in the orders. 

4. Display a list with "Product Name" and the "Qty Sold"

What i have so far (i am 1 week into php, so please excuse me if it's a mess)

```
$orderid = mysql_query("SELECT orderid FROM isc_orders WHERE orddate >= 1334266286 ");
while ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($orderid)) {
$pslm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isc_order_products WHERE orderorderid = '$row[0]' GROUP BY ordprodid");      
while ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($pslm)) {
    echo $row[2] . "</br>";
```

So this gives me a list of the products sold, but not grouped, and no qty shown of course. 

I have gone through a number of posts here, and spent about 3 hours trying to do this. 
Hopefully someone here can help. 

Thanks 

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what actually worked.

```
SELECT ordprodname, SUM(ordprodqty), ordprodid
FROM isc_orders, isc_order_products 
WHERE orderid = orderorderid AND orddate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ('$days' * 86400) 
GROUP BY ordprodname 
ORDER BY SUM(ordprodqty) DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a join and then group the results:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) AS quantity
FROM isc_orders AS o
LEFT JOIN isc_order_products AS p ON o.orderid = p.orderorderid
WHERE orddate >= 1334266286
GROUP BY p.productid
```

Or something like that. It's hard to guess exactly how it should be written without knowing how your database is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Elijah Madden already posted almost the same thing, but since I had already written it... here it goes:

```
SELECT 
    product.name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM isc_orders order
    INNER JOIN isc_order_products product
    ON product.orderorderid = order.orderid
WHERE order.orddate >= 1334266286
GROUP BY order.ordprodid
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went off your recommendation and actually ended up with this. 
SELECT ordprodname, SUM(ordprodqty), ordprodid
    FROM isc_orders, isc_order_products
    WHERE orderid = orderorderid
    AND orddate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ('$days' * 86400)
    GROUP BY ordprodname
    ORDER BY SUM(ordprodqty) DESC");

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest thing... you would probably want to get the product info (ie. name) from a product table, but here ya go:

```
$order_query = mysql_query("
    SELECT orderid
    FROM isc_orders
    WHERE orddate >= " . (time() - (30 * 86400)));

if (mysql_num_rows($order_query) > 0)
{
    $orders = array();

    while ($order = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_query))
        $orders[] = mysql_real_escape_string($order['orderid']);

    $product_query = mysql_query("
        SELECT *
        FROM isc_order_products
        WHERE orderorderid IN ('" . implode("', '", $orders) . "')");

    if (mysql_num_rows($product_query) > 0)
    {
        $products = array();
        $times_ordered = array();

        while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query))
        {
            if (!isset($times_ordered[$product['ordprodid']]))
                $times_ordered[$product['ordprodid']] = 0;

            $times_ordered[$product['ordprodid']]++;

            if (!isset($products[$product['ordprodid']]))
                $products[$product['ordprodid']] = $product;
        }

        foreach ($products as $id => $product)
            $products[$id]['times_ordered'] = $times_ordered[$id];
    }

    mysql_free_result($product_query);
}

mysql_free_result($order_query);
```